# The word's length with given alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Consider an alphabet $A = \{a, b, c, d\}$. How many words of length 8 can be created using the alphabet $A$, given the fact that it should contain 3 'a' and 2 'b'?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: It's useful to think about the process of creating the words. First you have to choose how many of each letter there are in the word. You already have $3$ $a$'s and $2$ $b$'s. The rest have to be: some number of c's and some number of d's, totalling $3$ characters. In how many ways can this be made? After this, you have to consider the possible permutations of the chosen letters.

Comment: A clarification: Do you mean **exactly** three $a$'s and exactly two $b$'s?

Comment: @lulu First, we have to create a word which would surely contain 3 'a' and 2 'b', like "aaabb000". Then, we have to calculate how many combinations are there for characters defined as '0'. This will yield 32 combinations. Then, we've to calculate all the permutations of 'a' and 'b' characters. And then I'm stuck.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes, exactly three $a$ and exactly two $b$.

Comment: For any such word, how many ways are there to populate the three empty slots?  How many choices have you got for each slot?

Comment: @lulu $2^{3} = 8$. I guess I misunderstood and therefore my calculations were wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick $3$ positions for the 'a' : $8 \choose 3$, then $2$ positions for the 'b': $5 \choose 2$. Now you are left with the number of words of length $3$ on an alphabet of size $2$. You have $2^3$ words.

Finally you have ${8 \choose 3} \times {5 \choose 2} \times 2^3=56 \times 10 \times 8=4480$ words.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general formula in combinatorics: if you have $n$ objects of which have $k_i$ are of type $i$, for $1\leq i \leq m$,  the number of words you can make is $\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_m!}$. That's because you first arrange the $n$ objects in one of the $n!$ permutations, then identify all such permutations that are obtained by simply permuting the identical objects of type $1$ (there are $k_1$ of those, so we need to divide by $k_1!$), and then do the same for the other types.